# Subset xts object using variables for start and end periods

Tags: r, xts

I have a xts object called 'usagexts' with dates from 01 Oct 15 to 31 Mar 18. I want to create 3 subsets of this object for the periods 01 Oct 15 to 31 Mar 16, 01 Oct 16 to 31 Mar 17 and 01 Oct 17 to 31 Mar 18 without actually hardcoding the dates as these will changes as time goes on.

The object structure is like so :

```
dateperiod,usageval
2015-10-01,21542
2015-10-02,21572
2015-10-03,21342
...
...
2018-03-31,20942
```

I have another data frame called 'periodvalues' like so :-

```
startdate,enddate, periodtext
2015-10-01,2016-03-31,1510_1603
2016-10-01,2017-03-31,1610_1703
2017-10-01,2018-03-31,1710_1803
```

I want to be able to create 3 xts objects like so :-

```
usagexts_1510_1603 -> xts object containing usage details for relevant period
usagexts_1610_1703 -> xts object containing usage details for relevant period
usagexts_1710_1803 -> xts object containing usage details for relevant period
```

I only got as far as creating a list of size 3 containing the periodtext from the above data frame. I was trying to somehow specify the start and end period for the xts object using the "objectname fromdate/todate" structure through variables but it didn't work - something like so :

```
usagexts_1610_1703 <- usagexts[var1/var2]
```

The LHS came from the list and the variables on the RHS cames from variable defintion done prior.

```
usagexts_1610_1703 <- usagexts[var1/var2]
```

Expected results should be like so :

```
usagexts_1510_1603 <- usagexts["2015-10-01/2016-03-31"]
usagexts_1610_1703 <- usagexts["2016-10-01/2017-03-31"]
usagexts_1710_1803 <- usagexts["2017-10-01/2018-03-31"]
```

Any assistance on that shall be highly valued.

Best regards

Deepak

Comment: when you say its not working, what error you get , pls update?

Comment: usagexts[paste(var1, var2, sep="/")]

Comment: var1 <- "2015-10-01", var2 <- "2016-03-31" - both are Date variables. >- The code "usagexts_test <- usagexts[var1/var2]" gives the error "Error in Ops.Date(var1, var2) : / not defined for "Date" objects". The code "usagexts_test <- usagexts[as.character(var1)/as.character(var2)]" gives the error "Error in as.character(var1)/as.character(var2) : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: your paste solution worked. Thanks for that!

Comment: Glad, that the issue got resolved . Have answered ur question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If var1 and var2 are variables, then the filter string can be specified using paste as:

```
 usagexts[paste(var1, var2, sep="/")]
```